# I need advice on sprintf and escape null

Tags: c, printf, malloc, free

I am learning to manipulate strings with `malloc()`, `sprintf()` and `printf()`.

But I don't know if it is right to add a null after `%s` format specifier...

```
sprintf(handling, "%s\0", source);
```

Because I am not sure if `sprintf()` have already included escape null inside `sprintf()` function code or do I have to add it by myself?

```
char * source = "Hello\n";
char * handling = (char *) malloc(sizeof(source)+1);

sprintf(handling, "%s\0", source);
printf("%s", handling);

free(handling);
```

I have compiled this code using GCC and there are no errors.

---

Code updated.

```
char source[] = "Hello\n";
char * handling = (char *) malloc(strlen(source)+1);

if(handling == NULL)
{
 printf("Malloc Failed");
}

sprintf(handling, "%s", source);    
printf("%s\n", handling);

free(handling);
```

Better? Or give me a some of example please.

Comment: You do not have to add it, but it won't change anything if you do, except to make your program one byte bigger, is the short answer.  The long answer requires an entire C textbook.

Comment: Important to know: When you do `sizeof` on a pointer, you get the size of *the pointer* and not what it points to. To get the length of a string use [`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen).

Comment: Thank you zwol and some programmer dude.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the return type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Comment: regarding: `printf("%s", handling);`  the output stream (stdout) is buffered, so the text will not be immediately output to the terminal until one of several things occurs.  In the current scenario, the data will not show on the terminal until after the program exits.  To get the data immediately shown on the terminal, end the format string with '\n'.  I.E. `printf("%s\n", handling);`

Comment: user3629249 - Thank you and code updated.

Answer (score 2):

> Because i am not sure if sprintf have already included escape null inside sprintf function code or i have to add it by myself?

You don't have to add `\0` yourself. That is already handled by `sprintf`

Your first code example has a bug:

```
char * source = "Hello\n";
char * handling = (char *) malloc(sizeof(source)+1);
                                         ^^^^^^
                                         This is a pointer so you'll get the
                                         size of the pointer instead of the
                                         length of the string
```

The size of a pointer may be 8 (64 bit machines) or 4 (32 bit machines). In the first case, your program will work but in the second case you didn't reserve sufficient memory. In any case - taking the sizeof a pointer is not what you want so your first code example is wrong.

Your second example it much better. There is no bugs in that.

However, notice that

```
char source[] = "Hello\n";
char * handling = (char *) malloc(strlen(source)+1);
```

could also be

```
char source[] = "Hello\n";
char * handling = (char *) malloc(sizeof(source));
```

because `source` is now an array and therefore `sizeof` will return the size of the array (which already contains the `\0` termination).

Comment: Understood. Thank you.

Comment: If compiled on a 64-bit machine, the first code works — but mostly by accident and only because the string is shorter than a pointer to it.  It is not good code.  On a 32-bit machine, insufficient space is allocated.  This trivia doesn't detract from the main points — nulls are added by `sprintf()` automatically and "make sure you've got enough space allocated".

Comment: @JonathanLeffler True. I updated the answer to include that.